# Phonegap: CSS is not loaded

Tags: css, cordova

I have the default phonegap project structure:

```
www
-js
-css
-font
-index.html
```

etc.
I also added a custom folder(f1) to the www:

```
www
-f1
--css
--js
--f1.html
```

f1.html imports css files from the css folder.
In the index.html here is an external link to the f1.html, but when f1.html is opened css files are not loaded.

Does it mean that a custom folder inside the www is not allowed?

Comment: Can you post your index.html to show how you are referencing these, and also any Content-Security-Policy meta tag that you have in the head section of the document?  Thanks.

Comment: Thx for reply.
`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />`
`<a href="f1/f1.html">f1</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I've placed f1 folder under the 'res' folder and it seems to be working.
In index html i have the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum- scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
```

f1.html has the same meta tags. Both pages have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And now i faced another problem, live reload is not working, index.html is reloading properly, but f1.html unfortunately is not (phonegap-cli logs that f1 was changed, on my phone i see that reloading happened, but changes are not accepted, the page is the same as it was before )